# Cannot connect to any remote database using SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I cannot connect to a particular SQL Server 2008 database server from C#.

I am able to connect using SSMS, and run queries using `SQLCMD`, but when I try to connect from C# using the `SqlConnection` it fails to open the connection with a `SqlException`:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Here is my code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Server=LDNPSM050000137\PLN000000014T;Initial Catalog=MiscData;Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    //exception occurs on this line
    conn.Open();

    //use connection

    conn.Close();
}
```

I get a similar response using ODBC:

```
string connectionString = @"Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=LDNPSM050000137\PLN000000014T;Database=MiscData;Trusted_Connection=yes;";
using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
}
```

This fails with an OdbcExcpetion:

> ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
>
> ERROR [HYT00] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]Login timeout expired
>
> ERROR [08001] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.

I have checked the server and instance name are correct, and the server is configured to allow remote connections because I can connect through SSMS. Does anybody have a suggestion of what the problem could be or how to resolve this?

**Update:**
In case this helps somebody diagnose the problem - This is specific to my machine/user account.  My colleague can run the code fine from his machine. I am also able to connect to my local instance using a connectionstring with the appropriate changes to the `Server` and `Initial Catalog`.

The error occurs for all remote database servers.

Comment: Have you checked to see if the SQL service is running, the first error you shown usually means that its not running.

Comment: I'd imagine it has something to do with `LDNPSM050000137\PLN000000014T`. Is that even a valid computer name? If you pull up command prompt and do an `nslookup LDNPSM050000137\PLN000000014T` what do you get?

Comment: You aren't specifying a database name

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Is the C# code running on the same machine that you connected successfully with SSMS?

Comment: When you connect with SSMS can you change the current database to MiscData?  You may not be a valid user of that Database.

Comment: @user2669338- Yes, the code is running on the same machine as SSMS.

Comment: @MikeBurdick - Yes, I am db_owner on the database.  I have also tried other databases on the server and it does not work for them either.

Comment: Have you checked Windows Firewall settings? ;-) It is easy to allow SSMS to connect on that port but nothing else. You might need to open that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is specific to my company's specific IT infrastructure - but the reason this was not working for me was because the project was saved in My Documents which stored on a network share.  Apparently .NET will not let you connect to a remote database server when the executing code is located on a network share - it work fine when I copied the project to my local drive.  I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I am not going to argue with what you are seeing, but I kinda doubt this is the real reason. Where the project is saved is irrelevant. There must be some other factor involved.

Answer (score 2):

Network shares by default have partial trust, so things that work when a project is on your local drive, e.g. connecting to remote server, won't from network location.

You can give the network location full trust (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdc263t0(VS.80).aspx) or move your project onto your local drive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the Server value in your Connect string:

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

I think you need to do this:

- Server=tcp:LDNPSM050000137\PLN000000014T
- Server=np:LDNPSM050000137\PLN000000014T

Depending upon whether you want to use TCP or Named Pipes...